# Dropdown select reloads to first option when reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select, dropdown

Hello I am having problems with the select dropdown. I am trying to store the value but it's not working. 
I have looked at other questions already but with no luck.

Here is a fiddle:

```js
function selectCss(element) {
  const a = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;

  document.getElementById("change").onchange = function() {
    localStorage['colorPick'] = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
  }
  window.onload = function() {
    if (localStorage['colorPick'])
      document.getElementById("change").value = localStorage['colorPick'];
  }

  if (a == "Theme 1") {
    document.body.style.background = "pink";

  }

  if (a == "Theme 2") {
    document.body.style.background = "blue";
  }

  if (a == "Theme 3") {
    document.body.style.background = "yellow";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<select  id="change" name="colorPick"  onchange="selectCss(this)">
  <option selected value="Theme 1">Theme 1</option>
  <option value="Theme 2">Theme 2</option>
  <option value="Theme 3">Theme 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code has several issues:

1. The value of the `select` and the `color` should be set if there's an item in the `localStorage`. This should be done at first instead of doing it inside the function.
2. It's better to use `else-if` instead of comparing the value three times.
3. The listener is already set `onchange` in the `html` element, so it should not be declared in the function.
4. You can define the element once and use it all the time.
5. You can get the selected value using `select.value` where select is the `html` element in this example

The working solution with the proper modifications would be as follows:

```js
let select = document.getElementById("change")
if (localStorage['colorPick']){
     select.value = localStorage['colorPick'];
     selectCss();
}
function selectCss() {
     const a = select.value;
     localStorage['colorPick'] = a;
     if (a == "Theme 1") {
          document.body.style.background = "pink";
     }else if (a == "Theme 2") {
          document.body.style.background = "blue";
     }else if (a == "Theme 3") {
          document.body.style.background = "yellow";
     }
}
```

```css
body {background: pink;}
```

```html
<select  id="change" name="colorPick"  onchange="selectCss()">
     <option selected value="Theme 1">Theme 1</option>
     <option value="Theme 2">Theme 2</option>
     <option value="Theme 3">Theme 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setItem method To store to local storage.

localStorage.setItem("colorPick", element.options[element.selectedIndex].value);

Use getItem method to retrieve

let colorPick = localStorage.getItem("colorPick")